# code that i've written works perfectly when in "if" statement but doesn't work in "else" statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run my program, if I give the right answers to the input, it works perfectly and logs in. But when I give wrong answer, it starts again and when it starts again on a loop, this time even if I give the right answer, it keeps telling me "wrong nickname or password." How do I solve this problem?

```
kadi = open('kullanici.txt','r')
sif = open('sifre.txt','r')
while True:
    ad = input('Your nickname: ')
    sifreniz = input('Your password: ')
    if not(ad in kadi.read()) or  not(sifreniz in sif.read()):
        print('Wrong nickname or password.')
        continue
    else:
        print('You succesfully logged in.')
        break
```

Comment: The second time you `.read()` a file, you've already reached the end of it and the result is an empty string. Also note that you're not checking that the password is the one that matches the nickname, and you shouldn't store passwords in plain text.

Comment: Onece you have read the file the file pointer points to its end and any read will return nothing. You have to reopen the file or rewind by `.seek(0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can read the file at once in variable , and then check in variable :

```
kadi = open('kullanici.txt','r').read()
sif = open('sifre.txt','r').read()
while True:
    ad = input('Your nickname: ')
    sifreniz = input('Your password: ')
    if not(ad in kadi) or  not(sifreniz in sif):
        print('Wrong nickname or password.')
        continue
    else:
        print('You succesfully logged in.')
        break
```